# convert adobe illustrator (or SVG) files into KineticJS Paths

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, kineticjs

I am using KineticJS to build a scene where I want to add some vector drawings to the canvas, and I have provided with lots of Adobe Illustrator files which contain shapes to add to the scene.

How can I convert these into the right Path properties to draw a shape in my KineticJS scene?

I saw this question: [Loading SVG in KineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538945/loading-svg-in-kineticjs) but they are asking about specifically SVG files where I have access to the RAW *.ai files.

Comment: [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) supports importing SVG and converting it to a programmatically-accessible and modifiable object

Comment: Thanks, but I am using KineticJS at the moment, are you saying I can use both or that I should switch?

Comment: I'm not sure about SVG support in Kinetic, but in Fabric we spend a lot of time on it, so I'm saying that it's a viable option :)

Comment: How exactly does it work? Does it just convert the paths and components and translate them into the equivalent canvas drawing commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Caveat to my answer: You need access to Adobe Illustrator...the free trial version will work!

**Check out Mike Swanson's AI converter that creates canvas drawings.**

If any .ai sub-element can't be converted to context draws, his converter even creates a raster image for that one element while still creating what can be context drawn.

It's updated for CS6 (the latest AI version).

http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/29634279264/ai2canvas

Comment: This is a great start, the plug-in works and creates pretty good html5 drawing code, which I can then use to create my own Kinetic.Shape objects and override the draw() function

Comment: How did you go about overriding the draw function?